# How to retrieve the data in data table

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, arraylist

Can you please help me in retrieving the data from the database into the data table. I have two fields which are (institutionName and institutionCode) to be retrieved. However, it is producing a parsing error in #{test1.getCustomerList()} while running which is coming from the value of the datatable. Below is my code:

```
<h:dataTable id="dt1" var="item" value="#{test1.getCustomerList()}" bgcolor="#F1F1F1" border="10" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="3" rows="4" width="50%" dir="LTR" frame="hsides" rules="all" summary="This is a JSF code to create dataTable." >
```

dataModel Bean:

```
package rfc;

public class dataModel {
    public String institutionName="";
    public String institutionCode="";

    public void setinstitutionName(String institutionName) {
        this.institutionName = institutionName;
    }

    public String getinstitutionName() {
        return institutionName;
    }

    public void setinstitutionCode(String institutionCode) {
        this.institutionCode = institutionCode;
    }

    public String getinstitutionCode() {
        return institutionCode;
    }
}
```

Bean1

```
package rfc;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;
import javax.naming.*;  // for JNDI
import javax.sql.*;     // extended JDBC interfaces (such as data sources)
import java.sql.*;      // standard JDBC interfaces
import java.io.*;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.annotation.Resource;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.SessionScoped;
import javax.naming.Context;
import javax.naming.InitialContext;
import javax.naming.NamingException;
import javax.sql.DataSource;
import rfc.dataModel;


@ManagedBean(name = "test1")
@SessionScoped



public class Bean1 implements Serializable {

        @Resource(name="jdbc/XYZ")
        private DataSource ds;
        ResultSet rs;
        private List perInfoAll = new ArrayList();
            Connection conn = null;
         String institutionName="";

        public List<dataModel> getCustomerList() throws SQLException{

                        if(ds==null)
                                throw new SQLException("Can't get data source");

                        //get database connection
                        Connection con = ds.getConnection();

                        if(con==null)
                                throw new SQLException("Can't get database connection");

                        PreparedStatement ps 
                                = con.prepareStatement(
                                   "select * from institution where institution_code = 'AAA'"); 

                        //get customer data from database
                        ResultSet result =  ps.executeQuery();

                        List<dataModel> list = new ArrayList<dataModel>();

                        while(result.next()){
                                dataModel cust = new dataModel();

                                cust.setinstitutionName(result.getString("institution_id"));
                                cust.setinstitutionCode(result.getString("institution_code"));

                                //store all data into a List
                                list.add(cust);
                        }

                        return list;
                }
        }
```

So can you please help

Comment: assign a property to your `<h:dataTable>` not a method.

Comment: It didn't work, Is there any good example that I can see or I can refer to?

Comment: check [this](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/data/datatable/basic.xhtml)

Comment: What you should have is `value="#{test1.customerList}"`. Post the actual stacktrace here

Answer (score 0):

I think that in jsf pages you must use properties without *get* phrase like this:

```
value="${test1.customerList}"
```

Comment: This doesn't work as it gave me a connection pool error in weblogic

Comment: Provide your exact error in your question. Can you view this page if you remove datatable component?

Comment: Since EL 2.2 value="#{test1.getCustomerList()}" can be used, however value="${test1.customerList}" is correct too. So if you get a different error it's possibly because of some other part of your code.